# Duplicate Columns when using the merge statement

Tags: r

When I try to merge some codes to the code descriptions I get 2 duplicate columns.  I start out with this:
Table Name: Test

```
ID     State
1      5
2      2
3      5
```

and want to merge it with this:
Table Name: statecode

```
StateID State
5       Mass
2       NY
```

to make a table like this:

```
ID    State
1     Mass 
2     NY
3     Mass
```

However, I get a table like this:

```
ID    State    State
1     5        Mass
2     2        NY
3     5        Mass
```

I used the merge command like this:

```
test = merge(x = test, y = statecode, by.x = "State", by.y = "StateID", all.x = T)
```

Is there a better function other than merge to use in this case?  Maybe one to just replace the state code with the state name?

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: `by.y = "StateID"` should be `by.y = "Code"` if `Code` in the second data set is state id.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however i wrote the tables wrong sorry.  I fixed them in the original though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do have to say which column you want to drop, but you can express it concisely using `dplyr`, for example.

Generating sample data based on yours (but correcting the column names):

```
test <- read.table(text =
"ID    StateID
1      5
2      2
3      5", header = TRUE)

statecode <- read.table(text =
"
StateID       State
5          Mass
2          NY", header = TRUE)
```

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% left_join(statecode, by = "StateID") %>% select(-StateID)
  ID State
1  1  Mass
2  2    NY
3  3  Mass
```

Comment: is there a way to not correct the column names?  I dont think i can change the State to StateID, sorry!

Comment: i have multiple code description tables for multiple variables as well.  I dont know if i can go into all of them and recode them all.

Comment: Isn't `select(-StateID`)` similar to  `a1<-merge(test,statecode,by="StateID",all.x=TRUE)` and `a1[,-1]`. Why do we need `dplyr` specific solution here?

Comment: @ChristopherYee you can exclude the column by position, but I think this is dangerous (for example, `test %>% left_join(statecode, by = "StateID") %>% select(-2)`. I think maybe it is woth the effort or renaming some of your columns, this might cause some initial work, but it can pay off with less chances of error in the future.

Comment: @user227710 we don't need `dplyr`, there are plenty of ways of doing the same thing,  I just prefered the "chain+verb" syntax in this case.

Comment: is there a way to add the letters "ID" into all the column names?

Comment: @ChristopherYee yes, you can do that by changing the `names` using `paste`, for example: `names(test) <- paste(names(test), "ID", sep = "")` this will add "ID" to the end of every column name.

Comment: hmm i tried that, but I could only get it to work on all the rows instead of just the columns.

Comment: @ChristopherYee that should work in a data.frame, you could try using `colnames` instead of `names` (for example if you are using a matrix you would have to use `colnames`), but maybe you should look carefuly at the structure of your data before doing that.

Comment: one more question, sorry!  Is there any way to get rid of all the "ID" in the column names after im done?

Comment: @ChristopherYee yep, `names(test) <- gsub("ID", "", names(test))`, but I think it´s better if you ask these as different questions, working with text is a whole different topic!

Comment: sounds good, sorry!  I am still getting used to how R and this site works!

Answer (score 2):

Another way with `base R`:

```
Pmerge <- function(df1, df2) {
  res <- suppressWarnings(merge(df1, df2, by.x = "State", by.y = "Code", all.x = T)[,-1])
  newdf <- res[order(res$ID),]
  row.names(newdf) <- 1:nrow(newdf)
  newdf
}

Pmerge(Test, statecode)
  ID State
1  1  Mass
2  2    NY
3  3  Mass
```